# A General Process for Finding Correct Bounds on Double Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So I'm working on some multivariable calculus homework, and I can't seem to figure out why my professor takes this particular approach to the solution...

The Question:
$$
S = \{(x,y) \in R^2: 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq sin^{-1}x\}
$$ 
And we have to evaluate $\int \int_{S} dA $

My professor's approach to this problem involves changing the integral bounds, so instead of the double integral setup looking like: $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{sin^{-1}}dydx$, it looks like $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{sin(y)}^{1}dxdy$

Can someone please explain how he got to this rearranged integral bounds setup, and additionally is there a general process for rewriting the integral bounds for a double integral?

Comment: Instead going for $x$ first, he starts with going along the $y$-axis. Draw it, then you'll see what happens.

Comment: @amsmath I realize he went for the y axis first, but I don't understand how he can go from a 1 to a $\pi/2$, or why the inverse sine becomes the lower bound of the integral

Comment: @amsmath And also I was wondering if there is some sort of general process for approaching double integrals where you'd have to switch the bounds

Comment: Forget about "general processes" in math. Usually, there is no such.

Comment: Have you drawn the picture?

Comment: I haven't drawn it because I don't understand what its supposed to look like :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two drawings that hopefully will be helpful for you.[image]

[image]